# Can we create dynamic infographics with timeline in OBIEE?

Tags: oracle, graph, graphics, oracle12c, obiee

Is there any way to make infographic with timeline in OBIEE that shows change of particular indicators for some particular period?

For instance, we have two measure columns : `profits` end `expenses`. User wants to see how these two indicators have changed for the last 20 years by regions. The infographic should show these changes with some delay for every year. Does obiee have this kind of feature?

Comment: Not quite sure I follow your question as what you're asking for is just a line chart with 2 measures which is about as standard as functionality gets

Comment: Apologizes for late response, @Chris, what I meant was we want something like timeline infographic that plays (like a gif) showing the change by year when an analysis or dashboard is loaded. For example like in this one https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/population

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to "play" the timeline, then pull the time axis into the section and click "Display as Slider".

Comment: Thank you @Chris, I will definitely try this!